# Merge two xml files using perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, merge, libxml2

I have two xml files of the type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="whatever">
    <types>
        <members>test1</members>
        <name>test2</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>test3</members>
        <name>test4</name>
    </types>
    <version>25.0</version>
</Package>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="whatever">
    <types>
        <members>test5</members>
        <name>test6</name>
    </types>
    <version>25.0</version>
</Package>
```

I want to concatenate these two using perl to produce the result

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Package xmlns="whatever">
        <types>
            <members>test1</members>
            <name>test2</name>
        </types>
        <types>
            <members>test3</members>
            <name>test4</name>
        </types>
        <types>
            <members>test5</members>
            <name>test6</name>
        </types>
        <version>25.0</version>
    </Package>
```

How can I do this using Perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with `XML::LibXML`. Basically it calls the `insertBefore` method to copy a node from the 2nd document to the 1st document. Tweak the script as you like, e.g. to do things differently if same nodes are found in both packages.

```
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml1 = <<'EOF';
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="whatever">
    <types>
        <members>test1</members>
        <name>test2</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>test3</members>
        <name>test4</name>
    </types>
    <version>25.0</version>
</Package>
EOF

my $xml2 = <<'EOF';
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="whatever">
    <types>
        <members>test5</members>
        <name>test6</name>
    </types>
    <version>25.0</version>
</Package>
EOF

my $doc1 = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string($xml1);
my $doc2 = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string($xml2);

my($version_node) = $doc1->findnodes('//*[local-name()="version"]');
die if !$version_node;

for my $types_node ($doc2->findnodes('//*[local-name()="types"]')) {
    $version_node->parentNode->insertBefore($types_node, $version_node);
}

print $doc1->serialize;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start at [XML::Merge](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3A%3AMerge) from CPAN

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @ajon: URL is now a permalink. Should never become invalid.